# Get gateway address in LUA esp8266

Tags: lua, gateway, esp8266

I need the gateway address for my ESP8266. I got the IP address and mask and gateway address for my esp8266 but I need only the gateway address.

How can I get the gateway addresss alone?

I used the `wifi.sta.getip()` function within the `nodeMCU` firmware.

Comment: and thanks for the help

Comment: `ip, netmask, gateway = wifi.sta.getip()`

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation plus example is at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/wifi/#wifistagetip

```
ip, netmask, gateway = wifi.sta.getip()
print(gateway)
```